# Cannot create embedded Derby DB

Tags: java, derby

I just cannot create Derby embedded database. I have tried everything in documentation

Same error

> The database directory 'C:\blah\blah' exists. However, it does not contain the expected 'service.properties' file. Perhaps Derby was brought down in the middle of creating this database. You may want to delete this directory and try creating the database again

I have tried:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:"+dbPath + ";create=true");
```

It didnt work

I tried setting derby path:

```
 System.setProperty("derby.system.home", dbPath);
```

It didnt work

I tried accessing embedded data source, same ...

```
private Connection createDB(String path) throws SQLException, NamingException{
    Connection conn = null;
    EmbeddedConnectionPoolDataSource ds = new EmbeddedConnectionPoolDataSource();
    ds.setDatabaseName(path);
    ds.setCreateDatabase("create");
    conn = ds.getConnection();
    return conn;
}
```

For God's sake, what am i doing wrong?

And no, i dont want to put service.properties in the folder, since then the problem with the log folder starts

Comment: Can you create a database using the "ij" tool that comes packaged with Derby? See http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/getstart/cgstutorialintro.html

Comment: Well, i need to do it automatically